# ¿Cual es el filepath de las imagenes que estan en la carpeta Resources de mi proyecto de C# en VS?

Tags: c#, picturebox

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion que dependiendo del modelo de un auto, te escoja cierta imagen para un pictureBox.

Ya pude poner la imagen en el pictureBox de la siguiente forma:
pictureBoxAuto.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.imagen.jpg;

Pero, lo que yo necesito es que se pueda poner por medio de un filepath, para poder hacer algo asi:
pictureBoxAuto.BackgroundImage = ("Resources/imagen"+modelo+".jpg");
Esto para que, simplemente mandandole un parametro que es el modelo, se cambie la imagen a mostrar.
Por ejemplo, tengo mis imagen llamada :"carro2012.jpg"
Entonces para eso ocupo saber el filepath directo de Resources, porque si lo pongo como pictureBoxAuto.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:/bla bla bla") no funcionara en otras computadoras.

Answer (score 1):

Cuendo la imagen esta como recurso no tiene una ruta fisica para accederla

Si quieres poder definir un parametro como string con el nombre de la imagen deberias usar el [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Recuperar recursos con la clase ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx)

entonces podrias hacer

```
Assembly myAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

ResourceManager myManager = new ResourceManager("Properties.Resources", myAssembly);

string imgResource = string.Format("imagen{0}.jpg", modelo);
pictureBoxAuto.BackgroundImage = (Image)myManager.GetObject(imgResource);
```

recuerda definir

```
using System.Reflection;
using  System.Resources;    
using System.Drawing;
```